# Passing cython memoryviews to OpenCV functions

Tags: opencv, numpy, cython, memoryview

I'm using cython memoryviews to refer to some grayscale images. I've successfully used this in some image processing code I've written. Now, I need to use some OpenCV functions. 
Unfortunately, I see I can't pass the memoryviews as image arguments to OpenCV functions. The code compiles, but when it runs it stops at the OpenCV function call with a "TypeError:  is not a numpy array"

I can convert the memoryview back to numpy array with np.asarray(my_memoryview). This works, but it copies the data and is slow.

In the memoryview documentation, they talk about coercion to numpy http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy
and it seems as if I should be able to coerce the memoryview to a numpy array without copying memory. However, If I write:

```
im = np.asarray(<np.uint8_t[:, :]> my_memoryview)
```

it results in a compile error: "Can only create cython.array from pointer or array"

Any help on how to pass a memoryview to an OpenCV function, or how to coerce the memoryview  in to a numpy array without copying the data would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get the original memoryview?

Comment: I get the original memoryview from a numpy array (which is an openCV image) like this:
cdef np.uint8_t[:, ::1] im2 = im
Then I operate im2, basically extract a subwindow(a memoryview) that then I pass to cv2.matchTemplate At the moment I'm using np.asarray(subwindow) as I can't pass the memoryview directly.
I think I may have missinterpreted the coercion to numpy documentation example, in that example they cast a pointer to memoryview and then convert it to numpy array with np.asarray which is the same I'm doing. However, I'm not sure if it is coercing or copying.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy/OpenCV doesn't take memoryviews, but it takes a [legacy precursor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#__array_interface__). You can create a wrapper class:

```
from cython.view cimport memoryview

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    object PyLong_FromVoidPtr(void *p)

cdef class OpenCVMemoryView:
    cdef object arr
    cdef object underlying_object
    def __init__(OpenCVMemoryView self, np.uint8_t[:, :] my_memoryview):
        self.underlying_object = my_memoryview # prevents GC of my_memoryview
        cdef memoryview my_memoryview_c = my_memoryview
        self.arr = dict(version=3,
            typestr='<u1', #typestr=np.uint8,
            data=(PyLong_FromVoidPtr(<void*>my_memoryview_c.view.buf), False),
            strides=my_memoryview.strides,
            shape=my_memoryview.shape)
    def __array_interface__(self):
        return self.arr
```

The [Cython memoryview object](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx) has attributes which return tuples like those `__array_interface__` requires.

If this is no faster, I would deduce your solution already isn't copying the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to try what you suggest but when I compile your code I get and error that I can't pass, the error is in `data=PyLong_FromVoidPtr(<void*>my_memoryview.view.buf)`

I get
                                                  
`memoryview_opencv.pyx:13:51: Casting temporary Python object to non-numeric non-Python type`


Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hi martinako, with the intermediate variable `my_memoryview_c` (that has a different Cython type) that part works. I edited my answer a bit, but my computer crashed before I got it working. If you get `expected a readable buffer interface`, you *might* need to use the commented-out `typestr`.

Comment: Hi, now it builds, but I'm getting a runtime error when passing the OpenCVMemoryView to cv2.matchTemplate : `TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array`     I've tried the commented typestr, it makes no difference.

Comment: Well, now I'm convinced that np.asarray is not copying the data. 
I converted a memoryview to ndarray using np.asarray and then modified the original memoryview, the modification showed in the converted ndarray. @r3m0t I really appreciate your help, and I still would like to test this OpenCVMemoryView class, maybe this wrapping of the memoryview is faster than the one created with asarray? On the other hand, my original question is wrong in that I though np.asarray copies the data and that was the motivation of the question. I guess I need to edit the question and explain that's not the case.